# Override a Standard Button "Mass Close" on Case object to Redirect to a VF page

Tags: visualforce, case-object

Can any one help out.

I have a requirement on case object for the Mass closer of cases.Since in Mass Close page we don't have an option to replace the field or add a field.To override the standard button "Mass close" on case object i have created the VF page.
But the page output does not look properly as we have for Mass close page.I get the section created twice.Any help is very much appreciated.

VF Page :
[image]

Code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Close Cases">
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
          <apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Case Information" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Status}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Reason_For_Resolution__c}" label="Reason For Resolution"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Comment__c}" label="Internal Comments"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c}" label="Do Not Send Email Case Closure"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I shall appreciate your help.

Comment: Having your VF code would help!

Comment: @ Santanu Halder : I have updated the code.

Comment: @SantanuHalder:Thanks for your quick response .Their is another problem Reason for Resolution is a picklist field ,but in Vf page i couldn't see the picklist value for the field.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: @SantanuHalder: I have 6 different Record types and 10 page layouts created and how to identify it.In Close Case layout i could not find an option to replace the button to override the VF page.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Well, you wont have option to override standard button functionality. You will have to create a new Case Button with action to open the VF page and add the button in the Close Case Layout.

Comment: And regarding picklist values in recordtypes. Open each recordtype and there you will see a list of "Picklists Available for Editing". Spot your Picklist there and edit it to see the picklist options assigned.

Comment: @SantanuHalder:I have Created a Button as "MassClose" with Display Type ="Detail Button Page" ,Content Type="Visualforce Page",Behavior = Display in existing window without sidebar or header.

Comment: The picklist field "Reasor for Resolution" is been assigned to all the Record types.

Comment: You have peak inside the picklist field inside recordtype and check if it has all the options listed there or not. Go in the same way I mentioned earlier and click edit link for the picklist and see the values.

Comment: And yes, add the button in the page layout. It should work.

Comment: @SantanuHalder:As suggested ,i checked for all the Record types ,it had the filed with the piccoloist values.In close case layout i could not find the option for the button to add.I could see only the fields and Report charts but not the Button option to add.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31354/discussion-between-santanu-halder-and-nikkey).

Answer (score 0):

Keep your pageBlockSection outside pageBlockButton tag.

```
<apex:pageBlockButton>
...
</apex:pageBlockButton>
<apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Case Information" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Status}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Reason_For_Resolution__c}" label="Reason For Resolution"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Comment__c}" label="Internal Comments"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Do_Not_Send_Email_Case_Closure__c}" label="Do Not Send Email Case Closure"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Anything you write inside `<apex:pageBlockButtons>` tag will be displayed twice as the tag is supposed to contain only buttons and the buttons are supposed to be displayed at top & bottom of the page.

Next, for the picklist values, make sure following things:

1. If you have recordtypes, you have assigned the picklist values properly to the record type.
2. You can see picklist values in standard page layout.
3. The field is not readonly by FLS.